# Template not being picked up?

Tags: nodes, theming, ubercart

I added a node-product.tpl.php file to my theme and it is completely ignored.

I reset the caches, multiple times, and tested with devel + devel_themer to see that the name was correct and it is. It says it searches for:

- node-product.tpl.php
- node-product.tpl.php
- node.tpl.php

Why would the core theme() function not find that template?

My only answer would be that somehow the theme path is not yet available in the theme() function at the time the product is being generated.

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming you are on Drupal 6, as it seems) you also need to copy the default node.tpl.php (e.g. the one from your base theme) in the same theme directory you are putting the override file (node-product.tpl.php) in order for the theme engine to pick it up:

> If you are implementing a suggestion, rename the file to the
>   suggestion name it should have. Note that some suggestion files will
>   not be recognized unless their base file is also present -- for
>   instance, if you want to make a node content type suggestion file for
>   your content type, you need to have node.tpl.php present in your theme
>   directory order for your node-my_content_type.tpl.php file to be
>   recognized.  ([Beginners guide to overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/457740))

Comment: Great! 8-) I think I saw that before, but it's just a bad gotcha... Thank you for taking the time to answer.